# Is there a way in SumoLogic to store some data and use it in queries?

Tags: sumologic

I have a list of IPs that I want to filter out of many queries that I have in sumo logic. Is there a way to store that list of IPs somewhere so it can be referenced, instead of copy pasting it in every query?

For example, in a perfect world it would be nice to define a list of things like:

```
things=foo,bar,baz
```

And then in another query reference it:

```
where mything IN things
```

Right now I'm just copying/pasting. I think there may be a way to do this by setting up a custom data source and putting the IPs in there, but that seems like a very round-about way of doing it, and wouldn't help to re-use parts of a query that aren't data (eg re-use statements). Also their template feature is about parameterizing a query, not re-use across many queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's a notion of Lookup Tables in Sumo Logic. Consult:
https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/lookup-tables/create-lookup-table/
for details.

It allows to store some values (either manually once, or in a scheduled way as as a result of some query) with `| save` operator.
And then you can refer to these values using `| lookup` which is conceptually similar to SQL's `JOIN`.

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.

Comment: Awesome. And it seems the `lookupContains` operator does exactly what I want -- a way to filter some query down by looking up keys in the table. https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/search-operators/lookupContains/#within-a-where-expression

Comment: So this works for data, but do you know if there's a way to re-use snippets of a query so you can compose a query from several others? In pseudo-code, allowing you to do something like `_sourceCategory=foo AND "bar" | filterIPs() | filterSomethingElse() | graphUsers()`

Comment: I don't think a thing like this exactly exists. There are scheduled views, but they are something slightly different - you define a query which is run against any new log data and then you can use the results of that query quicker.